# No output when trying to use nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, installation, ubuntu-14.04, apt-get

I installed node on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine with:

```
apt-get install node
```

However, when I run

```
node -v
```

there is no output.

I then tried `apt-get install nodejs`, and when I run `nodejs -v` I get `v0.10.25`.

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong to get node working.

My PHP script requires node.js and my check keeps failing:

```
if(preg_match("/^v\d+.\d+.\d+$/", `node -v`) === 0){
    exit_json([
        "error" => "Node isn't installed on this machine."
    ]);
}
```

How can I correctly install node.js on 14.04? I used digital ocean's tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Node.js as a developer in you developing machine I advise you to install it using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

Follow the instructions than add the following to your ~/.bashrc file:

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

After type

```
$source ~/.bashrc
```

This will allow you to use NVM to install the versions you want:

```
$nvm install 10
```

You can install older versions and use whatever one you have installed by typing:

```
$nvm use 8.4.0
```

Comment: There's no reason for NVM in this case... this answer doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: You could elaborate on "doesn't answer the question", his questions was "How can I correctly install node.js on 14.04?", I believe NVN is one, if not the best, way of instaling Node.JS on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: The problem is that the path isn't set. It has little to do with what method you use to install node.

Comment: His question is quite clear and he is not asking to fix the situation but for a good way to install Node.JS.

Comment: It's clear from the question that he doesn't know what the problem is, and has assumed that he's installed Node.js incorrectly or hasn't installed Node.js at all.  Neither are the case.  It's just that `node` isn't in the path.  By using NVM, you may end up with `node` in the path, but this isn't the root problem.  Your answer doesn't address the root problem at all, leaving this person with no clue what how to solve this sort of issue in the future.  Furthermore, there are many perfectly valid ways to install Node, including via package manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute it, make sure you're specifying the full path (or make sure `node` is in the path.)

Also, that's a very, very old version of Node.js you've installed.

Comment: That's common sense and not really related to the question.

Comment: @Matth3w Of course it's related to the question.  Node is installed, as evidenced by the output of `node -v`.  It's likely that `node` isn't in the path for whatever/whomever is executing this PHP script, which is why the whole path must be specified.  The next thing to check after that would likely be permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Try install like this :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```